# iphone app never runs on device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios4

I'm testing on an older iPhone 3G, I just updated it to 4.2.1, it's in my apple profile as a test device.  iTunes sees it fine, but I try to install the app and it never runs on the device.  XCode says no issues, but when I try to install from an ad-hoc archive it says that the iphone is not compatible.  I have the build settings on the target set to iOS Deployment Target 4.0 and SDK 5.1.  I'm also using Phonegap 2.0.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone 3G has armv6 architecture, check if that is supported with the build.

Comment: Under Valid Architectures it has armv6 and armv7 but Architectures only has armv7.

Comment: My first attempt with an iPhone 4 worked fine, it was on 5.1 though.  It's just weird that XCode doesn't even seem to try and run it on the device, it sees it in the list even.

Comment: I found out that Xcode 4.5 allows you to set armv6 as an architecture but never builds the libraries for it. Most likely it is also skipped for the app build.

Comment: I'm still on Xcode 4.3.3, if it doesn't build the armv6 libraries can I force it to?

Comment: 4.3.3 worked well with armv6, did you use this iPhone for testing before ? Check the device is added to the provisioning profile you are using for adhoc distribution.

Comment: I'm assuming I don't need to use ad-hoc mode really, and it doesn't work either way.  All 3 devices are in the profile, I re-downloaded and installed it.  The deployment target is 4.2.  My 3rd test device is an iPod 2nd get with iOS 4.2 also.  Same issues.  This is so strange to me.  I think I can at least get the iOS 6 phone to work if I update the SDK but then I lose 4.2 compatibility I think from updating XCode to 4.5.

Comment: I got it to work by changing the Architectures field instead of just the Valid Architectures field.  Now though I need to find a way to support iOS 6 and 4.2 if that's possible.  I heard XCode 4.5 stops at 4.3 support.

Comment: Unfortunately that is totally unclear for me how do we handle older devices support in the future, that is true that Xcode 4.5 skips armv6 and it has iphoneos4.3 as the lowest target SDK option..

Comment: I think you can install 2 separate versions of XCode on the system, but I'll have to try it at home first.